# cURL download multiple files from FTPS site

Tags: curl, file, download, ftps

I am using cURL (first time using this) to download files from ftps site from the command line. This is what i need to do:

1. Download multiple files from the ftps site that match a certain file name e.g. `Filename_csv_1998.zip` so I need to download all files with name `Filename_csv_[YEAR].zip`. Can I do wildcard in curl to pick up these files
2. I need to download these files to a directory in separate zip files

I would like to do this using curl commands if i have to then maybe use a script.

Is this possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if you want to get a range of years you can for example do something similar to this:

```
cd correct_directory

curl --ftp-ssl ftp://example.com/dir/File_[1990-2011].zip -o file_#1.zip
```